# VBA Excel: FALSE/TRUE instead of value for sGetPreTag_Simple()

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to use these functions in VBA (Excel) to add a note in a cell (via using a shortcut). The box opens up but instead of saving the text I entered, it gives me FALSE or TRUE. Do you know what's wrong with the function? Thanks!

```
Private Function sGetPreTag_Simple() As String
    Dim sNewValue As String
    
    sNewValue = InputBox("Enter new note", "PreTag Simple", "")
    If sNewValue <> "" Then
        sGetPreTag_Simple = Str(Date) + " (" + Environ("UserName") + ") " = ":" + vbLf + sNewValue + vbLf + "------------" + vbLf
    Else
        sGetPreTag_Simple = ""
    End If
End Function
```

```
Sub PreTag_Simple()
    Dim rngSelection As Range
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim sNewValue As String
       
    Set rngSelection = Selection
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(rngSelection.Row, rngSelection.Column)
        If IsDate(.Value) Or IsNumeric(.Value) Then
            sValue = Str(.Value)
        Else
            sValue = .Value
        End If
        If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
            sValue = ""
        End If
        sNewValue = sGetPreTag_Simple()
        If sNewValue <> "" Then
            .Value = sNewValue + sValue
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried to use only parts but it didn't work either, so I'm not sure which part of the function is incorrect.

Comment: use this: `sGetPreTag_Simple = Str(Date) + " (" + Environ("UserName") + ") " + ":" + vbLf + sNewValue + vbLf + "------------" + vbLf` In your code there is an equal-sign before the colon, this should be a `+`

Comment: There is an `=` sign in your statement as an operator

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now.